# Move From Middle Instead Of Top Left

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uikit

I wanted to be able to move my playerOne to point2 with an animation but when it moves it moves from the top left corner of playerOne to the top left corner of point2. I was wondering if there was a way to move playerOne from the middle instead of the top left corner to the middle of point2.

```
@IBAction func moveToPoint2(_ sender: Any) {
    playerOnePosition = 2
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.25, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
        self.playerOne.frame.origin.x = self.point2.frame.origin.x-self.playerOne.frame.height/2
    }, completion: nil)
    pickQuestion()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of what is currently happening is that you are editing the value of `self.playerOne.frame.origin.x`, for moving it from the middle, you should edit the [`center`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622627-center) of the view (which is `playerOne` in your case).

Somehow, it might be similar to:

```
@IBAction func moveToPoint2(_ sender: Any) {
    playerOnePosition = 2
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.25, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
        self.playerOne.frame.center = self.point2.center
    }, completion: nil)
    pickQuestion()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Completely forgot about the center value!

Comment: Glad to help 

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
self.playerOne.frame.origin.x = self.point2.frame.origin.x-self.playerOne.frame.height/2
```

Try This

```
self.playerOne.frame = CGRect(x: self.point2.frame.origin.x, y: self.point2.frame.origin.y, width: self.playerOne.frame.size.width, height: self.playerOne.frame.size.height)
```